# В течение или в течении?

Tags: орфография

Как здесь правильно написать? Предлог "в течение" или существительное с предлогом "в течении"?

"...на базе фантазии, прошлых знаний, расчетов, интуиции и ранжирования в течении процесса приоритетов образуемых критериев к функциям используемых форм для оптимального компромисса предвидимых противоречий..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"В течение" пишется, когда речь идет о каком-то отрезке времени, например, "в течение дня", а "в течении" - если говорится непосредственно о течении, например "в течении реки". В нашем случае речь все-таки идет о времени (пока идет процесс), поэтому правильно "В течение".
Вспомнился анекдот про аналогичное слово "в заключение": 
*По Красной площади бродит мужик с транспарантом, на котором написано: «Свободу Леониду Ильичу Брежневу!». Подошедший милиционер: "Ты че, мужик?! С чего ты взял, что Брежнев в тюрьме?». «Так по радио утром сообщили: "В заключении Леонид Ильич Брежнев сказал..."*

Comment: Да, спасибо. Анекдот этот уже сегодня читала :)