# В течении или в течение

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

В течение ожоговой болезни выделяют 4 периода. Или в течении ожоговой болезни выделяют 4 периода?

Comment: Неоднократно задавался: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40252/%D0%92-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: А по-моему ответ на этот вопрос противоположен ответу на вопрос 40252, на который ссылается @Aer. В этой фразе течение болезни - это процесс, а не промежуток времени, поэтому надо писать "в течении". Я бы открыл вопрос для дискуссии.

Comment: Вообще-то в этой фразе нужно говорить о **развитии** болезни: **В развитии ожоговой болезни выделяют 4 периода.**

Comment: _Aer: На данный вопрос уже ответили_. ===   Кто и когда ответил? Вопрос-то сейчас был задан про Фому, а закрыли Вы его ответом про Ерёму.

Comment: Согласен, вопрос другой. Напрасно закрыли.

Comment: Здесь - в течении. **В течении болезни**. Ну или, как верно заметили, в развитии. Поскольку не о времени речь, а о процессе.