# Как правильно написать в предложении: в течении или в течение?

Tags: орфография

Настаивать в течении (или — в течение) 3 суток?

Comment: Следовало бы закрыть этот вопрос как дубликат. Достаточно набрать  "в течение" в строке поиска.

Comment: "Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа" (из правил этого сайта: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вот старый вопрос о том же: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40252/%D0%92-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: ***в течение***. В данном случае это предлог, используемый в речи при обозначении времени какого-либо действия.

Часто путают предлог **в течение** с существительном **течение** с предлогом **в**.
Существительное **течение** в предложном падеже имеет окончание **и**: *в течениИ.*

Ср.: ***В течение*** нескольких лет в этом доме никто не бывал.

***В течении*** реки замечены незначительные изменения.