# Нужно ли здесь тире или запятая или вообще ничего не нужно?

Tags: запятые, тире

*На основании Договора №... от 12.03.2019 года между ООО «Газпромнефть-Хантос» и ООО «СК ПНГ», требование о замене ведущего инженера-технолога Бакланова А.С. — принимаем. Данный сотрудник будет заменен другим специалистом в течении трёхдневного срока.*

Comment: «... заменен другим специалистом в течении трёхдневного срока.» Будет короче и без ошибок:  заменен другим специалистом в трёхдневный срок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире не нужно. Запятая тоже не нужна на месте тире. Первая запятая после «СК ПНГ» также необязательна. Можно оставить только ввиду распространённости оборота.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно ли здесь тире или запятая или вообще ничего не нужно?

"Здесь" ничего не нужно. Тире, вообще говоря, возможно как интонационное, но в деловом тексте совершенно не к месту.

Но прежде всего нужно исправить слово: "в течени**е**".

***Данный сотрудник будет заменен другим специалистом в течение трёхдневного срока.***
Cм. тут: [В течение или в течении?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40252)

Остальное - сойдет.

Comment: *Но прежде всего нужно исправить слово: "в течение".* Точно! А я проглядел.)) А может, взгляд упал только на "трёхдневный", а всё предложение не читал, не помню.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да я вообще другой раз сильно удивляюсь, как вы замечаете мои описки и прочие грешки (за что вам спасибо) - и оставляете нетронутыми ошибки.

Comment: Просто я иногда читаю внимательно, а иногда проглядываю, и, если взгляд падает на ошибку/описку, исправляю, но полностью не проверяю. ;)